# Create arguments from command line and save in an array

Tags: arrays, c, loops, for-loop

I'm trying to save my arguments and their parameters from the command line as follows

`./run cat hello.txt : grep left : wc -c`

I want to seperate each argument in an array as follows withouth knowing the number of `:`

```
char *cat_args[] = {"cat", "tests/nevermind", NULL};
char *grep_args[] = {"grep", "left", NULL};
char *cut_args[] = {"wc", "-c", NULL};
```

How can I achieve this ?

```
int nbProc = 2;
for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++){
        if (strcmp(argv[i], ":") == 0){
            nbProc++;
        }
    }

int indice_debut[nbProc-2];
int j = 0;
for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++){
        if (strcmp(argv[i], ":") == 0){
            argv[i] = NULL;
            indice_debut[j] = i + 1;
            j++;
        }
    }
```

With this i'm able to get `indice_debut = {4,7}` because there is `:` in 4th and 7th position.

I tried to run it as this but no luck, i'm doing this so i can use `execvp`.

`execvp(argv[indice_debut[0]], argv + indice_debut[0]);`

Thanks

Comment: Allocate the arrays dynamically using `malloc()`

Comment: @Barmar the issue is i dont know how many arrays im going to make

Comment: You need at most `argc/2` arrays. So allocate that many.

Comment: can you show me in code please ? what about naming the arrays ? how will i name them if i dont know how many there is

Comment: You only need one name for the array of  pointers.

Comment: @Barmar please show me an example in code so i can understand better

Comment: Don't you need `n+1` arrays where `n` is the number of bare `:` characters found on the command line?

Comment: @JeffHolt yes indeed, i'd need n+1 arrays

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Allocate an array of pointers dynamically with `malloc()`. There can be at most `argc/2` commands, since the worst case is alternating `word : word : word : ...`, so allocate that many elements. The array elements can point to the elements of `argv`, and you can replace the `:` argument with a null pointer to end each subcommand.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    if (argc < 2) {
        printf("At least one command is required\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    char **arg_arrays = malloc(argc/2 * sizeof *arg_arrays);
    int array_index = 0;
    int arg_index = 0;
    while (arg_index < argc) {
        arg_arrays[array_index++] = &argv[arg_index];
        for (; arg_index < argc && strcmp(argv[arg_index], ":") != 0; arg_index++) {}
        argv[arg_index] = NULL;
    }

    // Execute each of the subcommands
    for (int i = 0; i < array_index; i++) {
        pid_t pid = fork();
        if (pid == 0) {
            execvp(arg_arrays[i][0], arg_arrays[i]);
        } else if (pid < 0) {
            perror("fork");
            exit(1);
        }
    }
    // wait for all the subcommands to finish
    while (wait(NULL) > 0) {}
}
```

This is just a simple example of how to parse the subcommands and execute them. If you want to pipe from one command to the next one you'll need to add that code.

Comment: I get these messages incompatible pointer to integer conversion assigning to 'char' from 'void *' [-Wint-conversion]
        argv[arg_index] = NULL;

Comment: warning: incompatible integer to pointer conversion passing 'char' to parameter of type 'const char *'; take the address with & [-Wint-conversion]
            execvp(arg_arrays[i][0], arg_arrays[i]);
                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Comment: test.c:26:38: warning: incompatible pointer types passing 'char *' to parameter of type 'char *const *'; take the address with & [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
            execvp(arg_arrays[i][0], arg_arrays[i]);

Comment: can you add the pipe example as well, just for information and general knowledge

Comment: Sorry, it should be `char **argv`

Comment: There are many other questions about creating the pipes between child processes, I'm not going to do all your homework for you. This question is about creating the arrays.,